# delphi indy IdDNSResolver not returning all the requested dns results

Tags: delphi, dns, indy

Based on the documentation, I should be able to add more than 1 query type in a lookup, but the result is always only 1 type.

For example, I set id.QueryType:=[qtNS, qtA, qtMX]; and I only get the A record back. Removing the qtA, I get 3 NS records back, but no MX. Each of them alone works fine.

Example:

```
id:=TIdDNSResolver.Create(nil);
id.Host:='8.8.8.8';
id.QueryType:='[qtNS, qtA, qtMX];
id.Resolve('car.com');
...
```

id.QueryResult.count is just 1, and it only contains the A record.

So how can I get all 3 types in 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS requests are described in [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035). According to this document, sending multiple questions in the same request is allowed, I'm assuming that's why it is implemented this way in Indy.

In praxis, DNS servers usually do not support this, and return only one answer even if there are multiple questions. You can find more info in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/742785/multi-query-multiple-dns-record-types-at-once), and the posts linked from there.

I would assume the DNS servers to answer the *first* question, so if you pass an array with multiple types, you could expect an answer for the type with the lowest id. In your case the priority would be `qtA > qtNS > qtMX`. If you need answers for all of them, you should resolve them separately.

Comment: Thank you for the details :)